# sahi scripting issue to record text of popup window

Tags: sahi

How to write custom script in sahi to record textbox text in a popup window?
Please, someone suggest me the main file, where I can write my custom function for sahi tool recording?

Comment: Have you ever used sahi before??

Comment: No shobhit..actually, I used to work on java only. But, for testing the applications I have to use sahi. Now I have a popup window in my application, where User is giving some input in the textbox and that is not recorded by sahi. It is fetching null at the value (like..label='xyz', **value=''**)..

Comment: I have provided two links.These will solve your problem. http://sahi.co.in/forums/viewtopic.php?id=3581 and http://sahi.co.in/forums/viewtopic.php?id=1169

Answer (score 0):

for pop-ups, use _selectWindow() API.
for ex:

_selectWindow("/1/"); //Here in Sahi controller you can see the pop-up window id in prefix field, you can also use id as regular expression if it's dynamic, as i've used.

_click(_span(15));

_selectWindow();